# Combining two SELECT querys

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2012).

I trying to combine the following two SELECT statements so that the rows from z will be added right next to the union of x and y.

But I had no luck yet.

```
The two SELECT statements are:

SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c
FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT y.a y.b, y.c
FROM y

SELECT z.d, z.e, z.f, z.g
FROM x
FULL OUTER JOIN z
ON (x.h = z.h)
FULL OUTER JOIN y
ON (y.h = z.h)
```

All three tables (x, y and z) contain the row 'h'.

Comment: Do you get any error? Or is the output different from what are you expecting?

Comment: Your question would be more clear with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get seven columns in your output, we you can do like this:

```
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c, z.d, z.e, z.f, z.g
FROM x
FULL OUTER JOIN z
ON (x.h = z.h)
FULL OUTER JOIN y
ON (y.h = z.h)
UNION ALL
SELECT y.a y.b, y.c, z.d, z.e, z.f, z.g
FROM y
FULL OUTER JOIN z
ON (y.h = z.h)
FULL OUTER JOIN x
ON (y.h = x.h)
```

Unless there's some reason why you need to join all three tables in both queries, it can be shortened to:

```
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c, z.d, z.e, z.f, z.g
FROM x
FULL OUTER JOIN z
ON (x.h = z.h)
UNION ALL
SELECT y.a y.b, y.c, z.d, z.e, z.f, z.g
FROM y
FULL OUTER JOIN z
ON (y.h = z.h)
```

You should also evaluate whether you really need outer joins.  That would only be needed if you don't expect matching values to always be in both tables.

Comment: Hello Mark, you are right - it is as simple as your second answer.
Thank you for providing help!